# Transferring a result in PDE from open domain to a manifold

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

Can anyone recommend me something that in detail, talks about transferring a result in Sobolev space (as opposed to Holder spaces or something like that) that holds for open domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a compact manifold? This would use partitions of unity and patching things together in some way. It could be a density result for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following books have good treatments of these ideas:

- *Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds* by Emmanuel Hebey
- *Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry* by Thierry Aubin